# Distinct by Attribute inside the item on my collection

Tags: linq, ienumerable, distinct

I have an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` collection, with N `MyObject` elements. 
MyObject is a class with a Title, a Description and an ID (as string).

I'd like to have my collection with distinct list of MyObject, due to the ID field.
So if 2 MyObject have got the same ID, one should be deleted (don't care which, I need unique ID).

How can I do it with LINQ?

Tried :

```
myList = myList.GroupBy(o => o.ID);
```

but seems I need a cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>`. Then you can use [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049) to filter out duplicates.

```
class DistinctIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject> {
    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y) {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj) {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now it's simple:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> distinct = myObjects.Distinct(new DistinctIdComparer());
```

Or you can use [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) what is even simpler:

```
distinct = myObjects.GroupBy(o => o.ID)
                    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants only unique id then you can try.

```
var uniqueIds = myObjects.Select(x=>x.ID).Distinct();
```

Or for Unique ID Objects

```
List<MyObject> objs = new List<MyObject> ();

myObjects.ForEach(x=>{
    if(objs.Find(y=>y.ID == x.ID)== null)
        objs.Add(x);
});
```

Comment: No! I Need a list of MyObject, and every MyObject should have a unique ID in the list...